# What is the difference between the following declarations?

Tags: c++, string, constructor

```
string str("Hello World");
string str="Hello World";
```

I don't seem to understand the difference between the two. According to my textbook, the operation that the first statement performs is "Initialization constructor using C string". So does the first statement define a C string and the second statement define a C++ string? Also please explain the difference between a C string and a C++ string.

Comment: [Initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization)

Comment: I think that your question is too broad. Please remove the "explain the difference between a C string and a C++ string.". If you need this information, please ask a new question (but it is likely that this question has already been asked).

Answer (score 4):

Both lines create a C++ `std::string` named `str`. And both initialize them from a C string. The difference is, how they are initialized:

The first is [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

```
string str("Hello World");
```

This calls the `string(const char *)` constructor.

The second is [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization):

```
string str = "Hello World";
```

This needs that the `string(const char *)` constructor is non-`explicit` (for the previous method, the constructor can be `explicit`).
We have a little bit differing behavior, depending on the version of the standard:

- pre C++17: first, a temporary object is created (with `string(const char *)`), and then the copy (or move) constructor is called to initialize `str`. So, the copy (or move) constructor needs to be available. The copy constructor phase can be elided (so the object will be created just like as the direct initialization case), but still, the copy (or move) constructor needs to be available. If it is not available, the code will not compile.
- post C++17: here, because the standard guarantees [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), only the `string(const char *)` constructor is called. Copy (or move) constructor doesn't need to be available. If copy constructor is not available, the code still compiles.

So, for this particular case, there is no real difference in the end between the two initializations, and therefore, both `str` strings will become the same.

Answer (score 3):

Both lines define a variable of type `std::string` named `str` that is constructed by the constructor of `std::string` that takes a `char const*` as its argument. There is no difference in those lines.

> [...] C string [...] C++ string [...]?

What is commonly called a C-string is nothing but a zero terminated array of `char`:

```
"foobar"; // an array of 7 const chars. 7 instead of 6 because it is 0-terminated.
char foo[] = "foobar";  // an array of 7 chars initialized by the string given
```

`std::string` however is a class of the C++ standard library that manages string resources of dynamic length.

Comment: So both the strings are C++ strings? And in both the cases the copy constructor of class `string` is called?

Comment: Both times you tell the compiler, that `str` should be of type `string` (`std::string` with its full name, i suppose). No, not the copy constructor (a copy-ctor takes one argument of type `class_type const &`). `"Hello World"` is of type `char const[12]` which decays into a `char const *` (a pointer to the first `char` of the array), so `std::string::string(char const*)` is called.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not being able to understand what you are saying as I'm not familiar with these advanced concepts. Could you please explain it in an easy-to-understand manner?

Comment: You know what a variable definition is?

Comment: So when `int foo;` defines an `int`eger named foo, `string bar;` defines a `string` named bar. Ok?

Comment: next, `int foo(42);` (or: `int foo{ 42 };`) initializes foo with 42. `string bar("Hello World");` (or: string bar{ "Hello World" };` initializes bar with "Hello World". ok?

Comment: Well I didn't know that, but now I know. Thanks. What next?

Comment: @ShashankKadambri Everything else is written in your favourite textbook about C++.

Answer (score 1):

"Hello World" is the c-string (null terminated sequence of characters). `string` (or `std::string` as its complete name is) is a c++ string (not null terminated) in both cases.

Both lines call the same constructor that takes the c string and constructs a `std::string`.

Comment: Since C++11 everything you get out of a `std::string` is `0`-terminated. It shouldn't concern the user how the data is represented internally.

Comment: @Swordfish it is a user concern once you have a `std::string` that has a `0` in the middle

Comment: @Swordfish i didnt consider it either until one day i had a myserious bug and only after weeks I relaized what was the cause, made a good lesson ;)